# is there any possible way to store temporary integer value in c# 4.5?

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, wpf-controls

I am creating WPF application. I need to store a temporary value in some variable in one method and I need to get back that value in another method. is there any possible way to store the temporary value in a variable using WPF?

---

From Comment:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    count++; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
    { 
        var tb = new TextBox(); 
        mycanvas.Children.Add(tb);  
        tb.Name = "txtbox"+i; 
        tb.Width = 100;  
        Canvas.SetLeft(tb,50); 
        Canvas.SetTop(tb, i*20); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: would you like to store in your WPF app memory or in a separated file?

Comment: in my WPF .cs file. i have two methods. in my first method i have variable inside loop. i want to pass the value to next method.

Comment: private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                count++;
                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    var tb = new TextBox();
                    mycanvas.Children.Add(tb);
                    tb.Name = "txtbox"+i;
                    tb.Width = 100;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(tb,50);
                    Canvas.SetTop(tb, i*20);
                }
            }

Comment: i want to pass the current 'i' value to the next method. is there any possible way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a bit of a misunderstanding here ...
WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation), is a technology that came to replace WinForms ...

Storing temp integers would be done exactly like it'll be done in WinForms, Console application or a dll.

You'll save it as a variable that the other method can see (depending on where it is), or send it as a parameter.

If you're talking about MVVM, things get a bit more interesting, but you can still store and send temp variables ...

Having said that, you can also stash away variables in the application settings, and use them (or their default values you can set) however you want. Here's more on this option: [MSDN: Application Settings Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
.

---

If you want to do something on every `i`, **Jossef Harush** is on the money, otherwise (or in addition, you can do something like the following as well:

```
private int global_variable_name;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    count++; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
    { 
        var tb = new TextBox(); 
        mycanvas.Children.Add(tb);  
        tb.Name = "txtbox"+i; 
        tb.Width = 100;  
        Canvas.SetLeft(tb,50); 
        Canvas.SetTop(tb, i*20); 
        // You can set global_variable_name here, but it'll be 
        // silly to set it to `i`, since it's changing
        global_variable_name = 8;
    } 
} 

private void SomeOtherMethod() {
    // you can use global_variable_name here
    var sum = global_variable_name + 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome you to StackOverflow, i agree with @Noctis answer.

In addition (after reading your comment),

If you would like to pass the current loop's index to a custom method, this is what you should do:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 10;

        count++; 

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) 
        {
            var tb = new TextBox();
            mycanvas.Children.Add(tb); 
            tb.Name = "txtbox" + i; 
            tb.Width = 100; 
            Canvas.SetLeft(tb, 50); 
            Canvas.SetTop(tb, i * 20); 

            // My custom method
            MyMethod(i);
        }
    }

    private void MyMethod(int i)
    {
        // Do something with i

        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```